# Need some suggestion on Stored Procedure using for GI

Tags: acumatica

Need some suggestion on our approach using stored procedure for GI. The reason we are using GI is, we need to export the data to other application using OData.

- We have only one company in our instance
- We are creating Temporary
  table first and stored procedure is doing all the required
  calculations and fetching data from different tables and insert into
  temp table.
- We are thinking to create DAC for the temporary table
  first and also a custom screen with a button which will execute the
  stored procedure. Once the DAC is created we will use this DAC to
  create GI.

My Questions:

- We have hosted our Acumatica instance in shared hosting, will this be
  a problem to use stored procedure.

Please suggest me is this the right approach or else please let me know some guidance to achieve this.

Comment: You will need some process before you open your GI to process the data. Is the Stored procedure simple enough to be converted to a view? Otherwise might recommend creating your own processing page in Acumatica to process the data then open the GI. Maybe someone else has a better option. In general I would suggest not using stored procedures in Acumatica.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This was along the lines we were thinking, but out curiosity, why do you suggest not using Stored Procedures?

Comment: You need to package the SP; Account for Usr fields and hope they don't break your SP; if using in a graph it will go against the caching of the framework;Not supported for ISVs; Will not work on a MySQL instance; Acumatica doesn't use an SP for business logic; no DAC freebies. The situations are very specific to your application. If one off for a customer then you can give it a try. I would recommend to write a process in a new Acumatica processing page to do all of the work. You can then schedule that process to run when needed or triggered from other operations.

Answer (score 0):

> We have hosted our Acumatica instance in shared hosting, will this be
>   a problem to use stored procedure.

- You need to ask your Acumatica Partner or Acumatica Partner Account Manager to know if this is allowed on Acumatica SAAS Servers.

> Please suggest me is this the right approach or else please let me
>   know some guidance to achieve this.

- It is not the right approach because Acumatica Framework has little to no metadata available about stored procedure. It can't inspect them and apply proper security. There are likely other reasons like compatibility between different DB provider involved.

> The reason we are using GI is, we need to export the data to other
>   application using OData.

- GI doesn't require stored procedure. You should look into other ways to populate the data, perhaps a process screen.